# ¿Cómo agrupar datos repetidos en una consulta SQL y pasar a JSON?

Tags: json, mariadb

tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no quiero imprimir valores repetidos como el caso de la columna **name_referencia**

sino por ejemplo:

referencia=8414 tiene todos estos datos de la columna conversión
8312,8307,8308,8313,8320,8305

y así mismo con los demás datos.

quiero obtener un resultado de tipo json:
ej con referencia=8314:

```
{
            "id_referencia": 256,
            "referencia": "8314",
            "name_referencia": "PECHUGA GRANEL BOLSATINA",
            "datos_conversion":{
                "id_conversion":[254, 249,250,255,262,248],
                "conversion": ["8312","8307","8308","8313","8320","8305"],
                "name_conversion": ["PECHUGAS BOLSA GRANEL X4","PECHUGA CONGELADA X 4","PECHUGA CONGELADA X 6","PECHUGA BOLSA X 2 BLANCA CONGELADA","PECHUGA CONGELADA X 4 PEQUENA","PECHUGA CONGELADA BOLSATINA"]
            }
            
        }
```

no se si se puede hacer directamente en una consulta sql, o en con php

Comment: conviértelo en array y después pásale unique(); luego lo comprimes en json ....

Comment: Puedes crear exactamente ese JSON desde la consulta, sea usando `CONCAT`, `GROUP_CONCAT` y `GROUP BY`, sea usando funciones de JSON disponibles en MySQL (solo a partir de la versión 8 si no recuerdo mal).

Comment: gracias @A.Cedano tal como lo necesitaba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando **GROUP_CONCAT** y **GROUP BY**

```
SELECT tabla.id_referencia,
         tabla.referencia, 
         tabla.name_referencia,
            GROUP_CONCAT(tabla.id_conversion) AS idConv,
            GROUP_CONCAT(tabla.conversion) AS codConv,
            GROUP_CONCAT(tabla.name_conversion) AS nameCov
FROM tabla
GROUP BY referencia;
```